# Anywhere where or anywhere?

Tags: grammar

Which one of these sentences is correct? If both are correct, which one sounds better?

- You can browse the web *anywhere* you have an internet connection.
- You can browse the web *anywhere where* you have an internet connection.

Comment: One hears both. I prefer the first but the second is not incorrect.

Comment: Both seem correct, first sounds better and the second should have a comma after *anywhere*

Comment: `anywhere where` might not be incorrect, but arguably it is redundant.

Comment: Both are correct, and I prefer the second.

Comment: I would use "anywhere that"

Comment: @WS2, Would you say that an extra ‘where’ is more preferable if they are not right next to each other? e.g. ‘Is there anywhere nearby WHERE I can grab a bite to eat?’ Thanks

Comment: @JUNCINATOR If you are going to add "nearby", then the second "where" becomes more usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is more appealing to the ear, but neither of the two are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the web anywhere *(adverb = at any place)* {[that] you have an internet connection.} *(= relative clause modifying “any place”.)*

You can browse the web anywhere *(adverb =at any place)* where *(= in/at which)* you have an internet connection. *(= subordinate adjectival clause modifying “any place”)*

Answer (score -1):

The first one is wrong but the second one is correct because you need a relative pronoun you can say : You can browse the web anywhere where = wherever you have an internet connection.

But in this case anywhere where is not very common

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).